# Content Place Holder Resizing according to client Screen

Tags: asp.net, html, css

A basic Website 
Which has a One master Page and severl Content Pages.Content Page are vary in size.
i think to give a permanent Size for content Place.but Clinet screen may be different. so i used a table and make three row's

```
<table height="100%" width="100%">
            <tr height="4%">header section</tr>
            <tr height="95%">Content Place Holder here</tr>
            <tr height="1%">footer Section</tr>
</table>
```

but its not working.
i googled it but doesn't get exact explanation.

Comment: http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/examples/csslayout1.html

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware the height is dependant on content when percentages are used, only if you give exact height will it keep to it. I might be wrong as I have not tested it.

Comment: its not as you think.Table is on master page so it fill the screen and then content placeholder is acquiring its height which for his is 100%.